# Backup git projects by keeping only a reference with the remote repository without saving the entire .git folder

Tags: git, backup

While running my scheduled backups I have to save many git projets (containing the `.git` folder) and I'm looking for a way to filter the backup operation in order to save only the reference of each project with the remote url of the repository without saving the entire `.git` folder which sometimes contains too many files that I dont need/want to backup (e.g. `.git/logs` and `.git/objects`); so that, when restoring the backups, I will be able to just `push`/`pull` without any problems and if I need to align all the repository to remote it will be enough to `pull`.

I tried to filter out `.git/logs` and `.git/objects` but I get an error when executing for example `git status`: `fatal: bad object HEAD`.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, Git requires all references in a repository to point to valid objects and, unless you are using a shallow or partial clone, every object reachable from a reference must be present.  A repository that doesn't meet these criteria is corrupt.

Therefore, it's not possible to just delete the `.git/objects` directory and move on, since all of your references become invalid.  Also, when Git performs a negotiation with the remote side as part of the transfer protocol, it will use the objects specified by those references as statements of objects it has, and will negotiate with the remote side (by walking the history) until it finds a common set of objects.  Since Git can't walk the history when there are no objects, the entire protocol won't work.

You can either re-clone the repository with a shallow or partial clone if you want to reduce the amount of data, or if you don't want to do that, you can minimize disk usage by packing the repository with `git gc`.  Those are the only options that won't corrupt your repository.